# How to integrate multiple file download to my project liferay?

Tags: liferay-6

I'm new in liferay. im trying to use the multiple file download. I downloaded the source code and I'm trying to integrate into my project.

I'm using Liferay 6.1

I have problem with the view.jsp. when trying to add the view that i downloaded to the view of my project there is some code like this

```
 <%@ include file="/html/portlet/document_library/cast_result.jspf" %>
```

where can I find this file. in the project that i downloaded there is no file like this, there is only one file view_file_entries.jspf.

source :

http://www.surekhatech.com/blog/multiple-file-download-for-liferay-documents-and-media-display-portlet

Comment: The file is either within Liferay, or within that custom plugin. At deployment time they both get combined into a single directory.

Comment: It looks like [you asked the question in a different way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46813428) as well and solved it there. Not exactly a duplicate, but a pointer that the same underlying problem has been solved by the same person. Feels like you wouldn't expect any more answer on this question?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the file you are looking for [cast_result.jsp on github](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/document_library/cast_result.jspf)

Comment: yes, under \liferay-portal-tomcat-6.1.2-ce-ga3-20130816114619181\liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3\tomcat-7.0.40\webapps\ROOT\html\portlet\document_library

Comment: So you can now hook this file in the way you want it